# Google no posiciona mis subpáginas web

Tags: wordpress, web, seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

estoy trabajando para posicionar la siguientes página web: https://metadatosxmlrdf.ga/ creada con Wordpress.

Con la búsqueda "metadatos xml rdf rss" esta aparece en primera posición.

Ahora bien, las subpáginas (por ejemplo: .../recuperacion-y-acceso-a-la-informacion-metadatos-y-documentos-xml-rdf-para-recuperacion/documentos-xml-para-recuperacion/), no aparecen con ningún tipo de consulta.

Están indexadas, creo que de forma correcta en Google Search Console, se añadieron los sitemaps y el robot.txt. Sin embargo, el Search Console alerta de los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el sitemap indica lo siguiente: (aunque por lo qué leí ya esta obsoleto y es irrelevante pero por si acaso lo adjunto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Creéis qué alguno de estos errores es el responsable de que no se posicionen las subpáginas de mi web?

¿Como puedo con Wordpress solucionar estos errores?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que instales la extension Yoast SEO para agilizar el posicionamento, él se encarga de muchas cosas acerca de el SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, esos errores son los responsables de que tu sitio no sea visible correctamente ante Google.

He visitado tu web y me arroja un error 522 (Connection timed out) por parte de Cloudflare.

Asegúrate de que tu servidor tenga potencia suficiente para procesar las peticiones que sean necesarias y que tu sitio no esté abajo.

Es posible que tengas que hacer optimizaciones a tu sitio para que sea más rápido.

Señalo todo esto porque quizá Google no detecta tu sitemap debido a estos errores de servidor.

Por otro lado, quiero resaltar el comentario que menciona el plugin Yoast SEO. Tanto ese como Rank Math son muy buenas opciones que se encargan de generar tus sitemaps automáticamente (También los hacen accesibles por medio de URLs apropiadas para Google).